# making an if statement for a uiswitch action

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to make a uiswitch button determine whether or not a certain float is used in my pay day estimator app.  Please check out the if and else lines...I keep getting errors.  Pleassse help.

code:

```
- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    float dailyRate = [self.dailyRateTextField.text floatValue];
    float daysWorked = [self.daysWorkedTextField.text floatValue];
    float grossPay = dailyRate * daysWorked;
    float taxRate = .72;
    float ssRate = .938;
    float medRate = .9855;
    float nillRate = 1;

    if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) medRate = medRate;

    else (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) medRate = nillRate

    if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) ssRate = ssRate

    else (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) ssRate = nillRate

    if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) taxRate = taxRate

    else (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) taxRate = nillRate

    float netPay = grossPay * taxRate * medRate * ssRate;
    self.dailyRateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", dailyRate];
    self.netIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", netPay];
    self.grossIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", grossPay];

    }
```

Comment: **I keep getting errors.** , what errors?

Comment: Pay attention to all errors and warnings. When you get one figure out why and fix it. Get a book on the "C" language and study it, that is what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolons are needed after the assignments.
The parenthesized test after the else keyword is an error and should be removed.

```
if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) medRate = medRate;
else medRate = nillRate;

if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) ssRate = ssRate;
else ssRate = nillRate;

if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) taxRate = taxRate;
else taxRate = nillRate;
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Worked like a charm!  Thanks @Zaph!!! :)